# Error when installing Sql Server Data Tools

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-data-tools

I am getting errors when installing sql server data tools on windows server 2008 R2 Enterprise Service Pack 1.

Here are error messages.

> Error 0x800b0101: Failed to verify certificate chain policy status.
>   Error 0x800b0101: Failed to get certificate chain for authenticode certificate.
>   Error 0x800b0101: Failed to verify signature of payload: SQLLS11X64

I installed all pending windows updates and also tried to installed Windows Root Certificate update.

Still getting same errors on installation.

Comment: You can follow this link which will help you on your error. [http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2801987](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2801987)